# Ecplise autocomplete primefaces attributes

Tags: eclipse, primefaces

Hej,

I build maven Project and i add pf 4.0.jar to javaBuildPath and 
`xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` to xhtml file, but eclipse dont work when i press ctr +space. It's say "No default proposal

Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

try this.

Window > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP > Add (xhtml